# What is App.js file in React? The file is way too long?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to mention that I am new to react and took over the existing project. The app.js file in the component folder is too long. Does this file update by itself, or is it ok to edit the file?

Comment: There is an abundance of information about this on google, try the react docs first!

Comment: It's okay to be new to React, but this question makes it seem like you haven't done any research before asking. The folks here appreciate when you've done your research, it usually leads to a more refined question which makes it easier for others to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **main file** in reactJs. It is the **parent component** of the application. All the components of the application are included in `app.js`.

No, this file does not get updated automatically, you as a developer have to manually update it.

If you want to edit this file then it's ok but as it will help you in exploring the application. Suppose you remove a component then after running you encountered an error, with this you learn how to resolve the errors. And if you want to add new components then you must implement in `app.js` so that it can be rendered and you can visualize it